# Проблема с url для страницы новостей и записей

Tags: wordpress

Нужен такой url страницы новостей: `mysite.ru/news` и url конкретной новости: `mysite.ru/news/42`

**Что делал:**

Создал кастомную страницу page-news.php, в которой организовал вывод всех записей категории "Новости".

url при переходе на страницу новостей: `mysite.ru/news`. Всё ок.
НО! При переходе на запись url меняется на: `mysite.ru/новости/42`.

Я знаю, что "новости" в url выше - это ярлык рубрики "Новости", НО если его поменять на news, то переход на запись вообще не будет работать. В гугле узнал, что нельзя делать названия page и ярлыка рубрики *одинаковыми*. Как же тогда сделать так, чтобы url страницы новостей был `mysite.ru/news`, а url записи - `mysite.ru/news/42`?

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А почему просто не использовать страницу рубрики вместо отдельной страницы? Если ярлык рубрики news, то в шаблоне category.php или archive.php тоже можно вывести все записи из этой рубрики по адресу `mysite.ru/category/news`.

- https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category
- https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyseventeen/1.7/archive.php

Если нужно убрать префикс `category` из url, то можно воспользоваться плагином [No Category Base (WPML)](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/) и тогда страница рубрики будет открываться по адресу `mysite.ru/news`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Всё прекрасно работает! Важное замечание: чтобы работал шаблон category-news.php в настройках меню нужно выбрать пункт новости из "Рубрик", а не из "Страниц". Это скорее для новичков (таких как я).